# Android: Get Bitmap from a 2D-Integer Array containing ARGB values

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, bitmap

Currently I have a 2D integer Array containing ARGB values of an image.
Now I want to get a Bitmap with those values to display it on the screen.

The Bitmap should get scaled as well, for example the image is 80x80 or 133x145, but I only want it to be 50x50.
Something like this, but as it's Android the Java classes are not available:

```
    private static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
        java.awt.Image temp = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage imageOut = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D bGr = imageOut.createGraphics();
        bGr.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);
        bGr.dispose();
        return imageOut;
    }
```

I already searched the API and Stack Overflow but I could not find any hints, classes or methods how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create a `Bitmap` object representing the original size image (your 80x80 or 133x145). You can do it with:

```
Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, bitmapConfig);
```

where `width` is your source width (80 or 133), and `height` is your source height (80 or 145).

Then fill this `Bitmap` with colors from your array. I don't know the exact way your array is built and the type of data it stores, so for the purpose of this simple concept explanation I will assume that it's just a regular, one-dimensional array that stores ARGB hex `String` values. Be sure to correct `for` loop to match your exact case:

```
int[] bitmapPixels = new int[width * height];
for (int i = 0, size = bitmapPixels.length; i < size; ++i) {
    bitmapPixels[i] = Color.parseColor(argbArray[i]);
}
bitmap.setPixels(bitmapPixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Then create a scaled `Bitmap` and recycle the original size `Bitmap` you created before.

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, false);
bitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: It's a 2D Array (`int image[width][height]`) containing ARGB Integer values (like in `java.awt.Color`).  But I guess your current answer may already help me out.

Comment: Ok, test it and let me know if this answer is enough for you, or you need some more clarification.

Comment: I think I got it to work using two for loops where I simply put the ARGB Integers row-wise into your `bitmapPixels`, sadly I could not test it because I have to port more of such BufferedImage stuff to Android before I can go on with testing. But as I read from the JavaDoc of those methods it theoretically should work. Otherwise LogCat will hopefully help me out.